# Copyrighted React Native components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have installed a component using yarn, but its documentation shows that it has "Copyright". So, should I mention the author in a comment in the source code, or how is that?

The specific component is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-indicators

Comment: Take a look at [BSD-3-Clause license](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)

Comment: It's not just the component. React Native itself is copyrighted. For every piece of software you use you should read the license agreement to use that software.